# How to update real Progress for copy for multiple files in Async task when I am copying data Through FileUtils Class?

Tags: java, android

How to update real progress on progress Dialog when I am copying multiple files  in Async task (DoInBackground) Through FileUtils Class in Android Studio?

Comment: Sharing what you tried is a good start. :) Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: please provide what you have tried.